# How to add an transformed object to set via iterating a list in scala

Tags: scala, list, loops, set, scala-collections

I'm new to Scala, I'm trying to transform and add an object while iterating a list in Scala, but struggling badly with syntax and probably concept as well.

I want to achieve something like below as we do in JAVA.

```
public Set<Manager> promoteEmployeesToManager(List<Employee> employees) {
    Set<Manager> managers = new HashSet<Manager>();
    for(employee: employees){
        if(employee.getExprience() > 5) {
              managers.add(promoteEmployee(employee));
        }
    }
    return managers;
}

public Manager promoteEmployee(Employee employee){
    return new Manager(employee);
}
```

I tried below code but it's not working. In the step of `saveNewManagers(newManagers.toArray);` the `newManagers` is still empty.

```
private def processEmployeePromotion(employees : List[Employee]) {
    val newManagers: Set[Manager] = Set()
    employees.asScala.map(employee => promoteEmployee(newManagers, employee))
    saveNewManagers(newManagers.toArray);
}
```

Then promoteEmployee method is like:

```
private def promoteEmployee (newManagers : Set[Manager], employee: Employee){
    if(employee.getExprience() > 5) {
          managers+.(new Manager(employee));
    }
}
```

Comment: In your promoteEmployee method, you are adding the new managers to a non-existent collection, is that name correct?

Answer (score 2):

So you have a `List` of employees and you want a `List` of new managers.

```
def processEmployeePromotion(employees :List[Employee]) :List[Manager] =
  employees.collect{case emp if emp.getExprience() > 5 => promoteEmployee(emp)}
```

This will return an empty `List` if the employees list is empty or if no employees qualify for promotion.

Comment: +1 for `collect` instead of `filter` + `map`. To Raj: If you still want to get `Set[Manager]` instead of a `List`, you can either use `.toSet` or just change the return type of the method and add `(scala.collectio.breakOut)` at the end of the call.

Answer (score 2):

```
 val managers: Set[Manager] = employees
  .iterator
  .filter(_.getExperience > 5) 
  .map(promoteEmployee)
  .toSet
```

Comment: Is there any benefit that `.iterator` adds in this case? Also I believe that using `scala.collection.breakOut` you can avoid `.toMap` step

Comment: @SergGr Iterators are lazy, so, having it here prevents having to build intermediate collections at each step. It also makes the use of `breakOut` unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala, `Set` is immutable by default, so the `+` method on `Set` returns a new set.

```
private def promoteEmployee(managers: Set[Manager], employee: Employee): Set[Manager] = 
  if (employee.getExperience > 5) {
    managers + new Manager(employee)
  } else {
     managers
  }

private def processEmployeePromotion(employees: List[Employee]): Unit = {
  val newManagers = employees.asScala.foldLeft(Set.empty[Manager]) { (managers, employee) =>
    promoteEmployee(managers, employee)
  }
  saveNewManagers(newManagers.toArray)
}
```

The major change here is the `foldLeft` which basically abstracts away the idea of looping and building up the `Set`.

An alternative strategy would be to have `promoteEmployee` return an `Option[Manager]`; you can think of `Option` as being like a collection of at most one element.

```
private def promoteEmployee(employee: Employee): Option[Manager] =
  if (employee.getExperience > 5) {
    Option(new Manager(employee))
  } else {
     None
  }

private def promotedEmployees(employees: Iterable[Employee]): Set[Manager] =
  employees.flatMap(promoteEmployee).toSet  // NB: might not work if Manager doesn't obey the equality contract...

private def processEmployeePromotion(employees: List[Employee]): Unit = {
  saveNewManagers(promotedEmployees(employees.asScala).toArray)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you start to work with Scala you have to get used to work with immutable data structures, foldables, expressions... etc . You can still work with mutable as you used to do with Java if you want but the first is what you should do.

Look at this example using foldLeft from List:

```
case class Employee(id: String, name: String, experience: Int)
case class Manager(employee: Employee)

object Your_Code extends App {
  def promoteEmployee(employee: Employee) =
    Manager(employee)

  def promoteEmployeesToManager(list: List[Employee]) : Set[Manager] = {
    list.foldLeft(Set[Manager]())((a, b) => if(b.experience > 5) a + promoteEmployee(b) else a)
  }

  val employess = List(Employee("id1", "name1", 6), Employee("id1", "name1", 4))
  println(promoteEmployeesToManager(employess))
}
```